# Checking the consistency and Bias of $\frac{\sum X_i +\sqrt{n}/2}{n+\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. $B(1,\theta)$ random variables, $0<\theta<1$. Then, as an estimator $\theta$, check if $T(X_1,\ldots,X_n)= \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i +\sqrt{n}/2}{n+\sqrt{n}}$ is consistent and/or unbiased.

$$T=\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i +\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$$

$$T=\frac{\bar{X} +\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$$

$$E(T)=\frac{E(\bar{X} +\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}})}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}=\dfrac{\theta +\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}.$$

So, $T$ is biased.

Consistency: $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}E(T)=\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\dfrac{E(\theta +\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}})}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$

So $T$ is consistent.

But The given answer is "neither unbiased nor consistent"

Where did I go wrong ? Please advise.

Comment: I had thought at first that by $B(1,\theta)$ you meant the Beta distribution, but it appears you may have meant the binomial distribution.

Comment: I saw B and thought binomial .. How would one know if B is binomial or Beta ? coz for beta .. your answer would have worked I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wrote $B(1,\theta)$ rather than $\mathrm{Bin}(1,\theta)$, I thought at first that you meant the Beta distribution, but it now appears you meant the binomial distribution.  Assuming that, the expected value of each observation is $\theta$ and your proofs of bias and consistency are correct.  Perhaps if you quote the source of what you call "the given answer" more completely, then I could shed more light.

Comment: Comparing B(n,p) with B(1,theta), I took mean as np=1*theta. From first principles, f(x) should be something like $nC_k p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ .. I am lost right now ..

Comment: If $E(X)=\frac{1}{1+p}$ .. what would be an example of unbiased estimator here ?

Comment: I have edited my answer in view of your first comment. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Could you please also give that beta distribution answer .. that was new to me .. Thanks

Comment: Recall that$$
\int_0^1 x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}\,dx = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}.
$$
Then we have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}(X) & =\int_0^1 xf_X(x)\,dx = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \int_0^1 x x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}\,dx =\cdots
\end{align} ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $\displaystyle\cdots = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \int_0^1 x^{(\alpha+1)-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}\,dx = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\cdot \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma((\alpha+1)+\beta)} = \cdots$ ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $\displaystyle\cdots=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\cdot\frac{\Gamma( \alpha +\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+1)} = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}.$ ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: So we would get $\dfrac1{1+\theta}$ as the expecte value if the Beta($1,\theta$) distribution had been intended. ${}\qquad{}$